# Azure доступ к FileStorage из WebApplication Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure

Приветствую ! 
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, необходимо иметь возможность загрузки файлов в FileStorage из WebApplication Service с помощью VirtualNetwork на платформе Azure, для этого созданы ресурсы :

1. WebApplication Service
2. StorageAccount
3. VirtualNetwork

Все созданные ресурсы находятся в общей ресурсной группе, у StorageAccount настроен firewall в который включена subnet созданной VirtualNetwork, WebApplication так же подключена к VirtualNetwork.

WebApplication представляет из себя Asp.Net Core приложение, работа с хранилищем происходит с помощью SDK Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. 
При попытке установить связь с хранилищем получаю ошибку 403.

Подскажите что я упускаю в настройках ?

Спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению на данный момент azure не реализовало данный вид взаимодействия 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s